# Getting started with Coverity for python package

Tags: python, coverity

I downloaded the coverity package for Python/PHP, and try to
let it analyze my package:

```
./cov-build --dir cov-int --fs-capture-search /my/dir/ python mine.py
```

considering that 'my/dir' contains the package's root directory and the 'mine.py' implements the entry point.

The I get the result:

```
command line: No input files.
[STATUS] Running filesystem capture search...
[STATUS] Emitting 485 source files from filesystem capture
|0----------25-----------50----------75---------100|
****************************************************
[WARNING] Build command python /tmp/trunk/quex-exe.py exited with code 255. Please verify that the build completed successfully.
```

It is not clear to me, what Coverity means with 'build'. Does it mean a sample invocation of the script? How can I get started?

The most of the 'help' files in the 'doc/' subdirectory are empty(!)

Answer (score 2):

```
[WARNING] Build command python /tmp/trunk/quex-exe.py exited with code 255. Please verify that the build completed successfully.
```

This means that the command you specified on the cov-build line (`python mine.py`) didn't exit with zero. Probably because of this:

```
command line: No input files.
```

But in any case, it looks like cov-build *did* successfully capture 485 source files, so it's possible you don't need to use a build command at all. In that case, you can specify the `--no-command` switch and omit `python mine.py`, at which point you can proceed with the rest of the workflow.

Comment: Neither works. (i) specifying a command line so that Quex does not complain => zero files emitted. (ii) using --no-command => zero files emitted. 'cov-configuration' says that python is not available on plattform(?). How can this be, if I downloaded the Python-version of coverity?

Comment: Have you inspected the build log under `cov-init/build-log.txt`? It's possible that `cov-build` is capturing the files, but failing to emit them due to parse errors or other issues.

As for the cov-configure issue, I'm not sure what would cause that. I take you see that error message when you run `cov-configure --python`?